# Endpoints/Network security Group not created on Migration Classic to ARM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I had just migrated a VM(on cloud service) from classic deployment model to ARM using these [Steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-cli-migration-classic-resource-manager). Migrated successfully all works fine but I can't find endpoint configured on classic port. As my understand there should be created network security group on ARM. Should I need to create new network security group? How can I enable/disable/edit endpoint configured from classic model on resource manger model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I need to create new network security group?

Yes. **The Endpoint ACLs is not supported the migration**. After migrate VM from ASM to ARM, your VM does not associate a NSG. So, you had better add a new Azure NSG.

Here is an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-migration-classic-resource-manager?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json#unsupported-features-and-configurations) about the unsupported features and configurations during the migration.
[image]

> How can I enable/disable/edit endpoint configured from classic
>   model on resource manger model?

Based on my knowledge, for now, this does not support by Azure. You need create NSG rules for your VMs.

Comment: Another issue, after migrating there is no data on percentage CPU usage on metric, is it issue caused by storage? For migrated VM, I have storage account on ASM.

Comment: I enabled all logs and services form _Diagnostics settings_, still not appearing disk,network and cpu usage on monitoring but from _Metrics_ I can see all details by selecting resource and metric.

Comment: I have done all test, but not showing status on `Overview>Monitoring`, better option is to go `MONITORING>Metrics` and choose specific metric

Answer (score 0):

> How can I enable/disable/edit endpoint configured from classic model on resource manger model?

You can't. During the conversion to ARM a public IP will be assigned to the VM. As you have a public IP directly assigned to a VM (instead of a public IP on a cloud service load balancing services inside it) there is no point in having endpoints. All traffic to that public IP will hit your VM directly, there is no port forwarding, and you should filter it as replied previously with an NSG.